# Automatically update a graph based on parameter changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want a graph to update when parameter values are changed or periodically. I have the following code:

```
a=0`
b=50
c=100

def sine(x,y,l):
    A=numpy.zeros(l)
    for i in range(l):
        A[i]=numpy.sin(2*math.pi*(i+x)/y)
    return A


def plot(l):
    matplotlib.pyplot.clf()
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(l)

plot(sine(a,b,c))`
```

`

How do I get the plot function to re-run every time a/b/c is updated or periodically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few things here, you should learn about the proper use of numpy ufuncs which operate on ndarrays without having to loop over them:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/ufuncs.html

Secondly, you have to have a place where an update event is triggered, for example:

http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/events.html

Since there are no such examples in this code, I will just assume you know where that is going to happen.  Wherever that happens, then you need a handle of the line in order to update the data.

https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_xdata
https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_ydata

Here is some example code highlighting what I believe you are trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, l)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)  # generate figure and axes objects so that we have handles for them
curve = ax.plot(x, y)[0]  # capture the handle for the lines object so we can update its data later

# now some kind of event happens where the data is changed, and we update the plot
y = np.cos(x)  # the data is changed!
curve.set_ydata(y)

# necessary if you are just executing this as a script
# this example is a little more clear if executed stepwise in ipython
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: are the ufuncs more efficient than looping?

Comment: Yes. Aside from the code being cleaner and more concise, computationally it is probably an order of magnitude faster if not more because the entire calculation is handled in one c function call. In fact looping over a numpy array can be slower than looping through a python list due to the overhead of the many functions calls you would make in a loop